# Where are the WordPress capabilities stored?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I know the roles and capabilities are stored in the `wp_options` table with the `option_name = wp_user_roles`. It has a list of `roles` assigned with all the `capabilities`.

So my question is, if I want to just get the list of all the available `capabilities`, do I need to go through each of the `roles` and its' `capabilities` to get the full list or is it all stored somewhere?

Comment: You can use wp_roles() to get the global WP_Roles instance.

Comment: thanks, yeah, I was just curious if it is stored somewhere in the database

Comment: get_option( $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'user_roles' );

Answer (score 1):

Since 'Administrator' has all capabilities (unless you have a Multisite setup), just get a list of all the caps in the Admin role:

```
$admin_caps = get_role('administrator')->capabilities;
```